# Only sometimes, since two days: CurlException: 60: SSL certificate problem

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, facebook-php-sdk

Sometimes this appears, sometime not. Its since two days in former good running apps.

CurlException: 60: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed thrown in

With a former Version of the php SDK, I disabled CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER generally besause that never works. But the last two versions, now its the newest, worked until yesterday.Shout I disable something again? Is it the same method in the actual SDK? Writing from home, can't look inside.

Is it a message from the cert coming with the sdk or are that problems with the cert of https on my server?

Comment: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't disable `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` because of the security implications. The PHP SDK usually contains the needed certificate, but in your case it seems to have problems.

The best way to solve it is:

- Download the Facebook SSL certificate [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/raw/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt)
- Put it somewhere accessible by PHP
- Tell the Facebook PHP SDK to use it:

  ```
  Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = '/path/to/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt';
  ```

Comment: Path hasn´t change it. I think, The message would be another, if Curl doesn't found the cert. 

The cert itself downloaded is the same than befor, and, as I said, sometimes it works, sometime not.

When I understand rigth, this cert tries to open the Curl connect via SSL. Because no changes on my server or apps, I think Facebook has this problems. 

Securitiy is good, but when my apps doenst work with it, what should I do else than disable Verifypeer?

Comment: I based my answer on what I found on the internet. Several users reported the exact same problem you have, and most of them fixed it by manually specifying the path to the certificate. I have about two dozen Facebook apps online right now, and I have never experienced problems with the SSL connection. If you can't get it to work, then by all means disable `VERIFYPEER`! I just pointed out that it should only be used as a last resort :) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same error (coworkers didn't have it) and the solution was to download a new copy of the Facebook API SDK from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk. Apparently my version (and the certificate) was outdated.